# Gradle 1.12 cache

Tags: java, build, gradle

I'm upgrading my gradle wrapper from 1.0.3 milestone to 1.12.

I was curious whether the cache directory is still under USER_HOME/.gradle/cache.

How can I find out what is the cache directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I'm answering my own question.

After a lot of searching I've found out that the cache folder is not under **USER_HOME/.gradle/cache** anymore but in **.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1**